# Listbox code from As Variant to As Long

Tags: listbox, excel-2010

I've learned that the As Long is much better than As Variant when it come to improving macro speed.

```
Dim data1() As Variant
data1 = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
Sheet1.ListBox1.List = data1
```

When I replace with As Long, my code doesn't work any more.

Comment: If one of our answers helped you, consider accepting it (click the green checkmark on the left of the best answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your array doesn't contain `Long`s, it contains `String`s. Try `Dim data1() As String`. (Don't worry - it's probably still faster than `As Variant`.)

Answer (score 1):

While using explicit types is *usually* (almost always) better. This case is an exception because the `List` property of the `ListBox` is a `Variant array` anyway, so assigning a `String` or `Long` array to it causes an implicit type cast, so isn't any faster (and may even be slower).

What may make the difference is how you are loading data into the array before assigning it to the `ListBox`.  If *thats* more efficient use explicit typed arrays then fine, use it.

BTW

```
Dim data1() as long
data1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

doesn't work because `Array(...)` returns a `Varaint array` which can't be assigned to an explicit typed array.